# Different versions of the same script with packages on the same python installation

Tags: python, installation

I have a script, which contains some packages/modules. Now, the development and the production environment run on the same server on the same python installation (version 2.6). What is the best way to manage my script so that it would be easy to change the development or the production version of the script (eg install latest trunk to dev or install stable version to production)?

There is one related question/answer: [Using different versions of a python library in the same process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587776/using-different-versions-of-a-python-library-in-the-same-process/1588164#1588164)
But I'd like to know, is there a more standard way for this than renaming libA to libA_dev etc.

For example, I could have configuration file for both environments. The path of the libs is specified (libA, libA_dev). I could have 2 different setup scripts (or make on configurable) which indicate, where to install packages. And now my executable should read the configuration (from the working path) and import only packages from specified path. I don't know, whether it is doable? And is it the "standard" way for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not totally clear to me.

Do you want to deploy different branches of your application to your development and productions servers? It's a version control/deployment question then.

On the other hand, if you want to install the package (i.e. your application) into different Python "environments" (e.g. One with ver1 of the dependent libraries and the other ver 2), they the tool of choice is [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to rephrase myself.

Comment: I accidentally pressed enter within the last comment, wasn't able to modify it anymore. Here: Sorry, I'll try to rephrase myself. Actually it's somewhat both. I want to deploy different versions/branches in different "environments" (but on the same server and on the same python installation). I checked out the virtualenv. I think it does what I need. Though, I still have to change the executable script to change to interpreter (#!/path/to/ENV/bin/python for both executable)? Ideally I'd just "install" my app to env1 or env2. And it should work out of box. But I will try it out!

Comment: If your #! line reads `/usr/bin/env python`, then running the `activate` script inside the virtualenv will pick up the right interpreter.

Comment: I finally got it to work I guess. But, if I have a script which uses my own module. For example `mytest.helloworld()`. And I have different environments with different versions of `mytest`, can I just run my script? It does use to correct version of my module when I do `python script.py`, but running it directly `./script.py` doesn't work (it uses the version I have installed on the main python environment). Can my script be run in active env so that it uses correct version of my module?